# Leaflet Center Marker Numbers

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

Does anyone have an idea how to center numbers inside markers? This is the current situation.

[Marker with Number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBBrf.jpg)

**Creating a Marker**

```
    return L.divIcon({
  className: "green-icon",
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [10, 44],
  popupAnchor: [3, -40],
  html: markerNumber,
});
```

**CSS**

```
.green-icon {
 background-image: url("../GreenIcon.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```js
 return L.divIcon({
  className: "green-icon",
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [10, 44],
  popupAnchor: [3, -40],
  html: `<span class="icon-text">${markerNumber}</span>`
})
```

Add this to your CSS.

```css
.icon-text {
  text-align: center;
}

.green-icon {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
}
```

JSfiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/greedygod/jxk8fe1q/4/)